# При попытке сохранить данные ошибка: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'commit'

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3

При попытке сохранить внесенные данные выдает ошибку, что команда не имеет атрибута commit:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Command' object has no attribute 'commit'

Часть кода, где выдает ошибку

```
    sql.execute("UPDATE balance SET balanc = 1000 WHERE id = 829768910458191892")
    db.commit()
```

Код инициализации бд

```
db = sqlite3.connect('balanc.db')
sql = db.cursor()



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")
    sql.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS balance (
        id INT,
        name TEXT,
        balanc BIGINT,
        rep INT
        )
        """)
```

Comment: @MaxU Да, спасибо это подошло.

Comment: оформил как ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже вы где-то в коде переприсвоили значение переменной `db` каким-то `Command` обьектом, у которого в отличие от объекта `sqlite3.connect` нет атрибута/метода `commit`.

Чтобы убедиться сделайте:

```
print(type(db))
```